# Can't received a result in C# code when run a Stored procedure through SqlCommend

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

Please find my tables, data, SP and C# code.

**Table structure:**

```
create table ExTest
(
Id int Identity(1,1) primary key,
IsDeleted BIT default 0,
DeleteDate DateTime
)
```

=====================================================

**Table data:**

```
Id  IsDeleted   DeleteDate
1   0          2017-07-10 09:12:03.960
2   0          2017-07-10 09:12:07.000
```

==========================================================

**Stored procedure:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateAndSelect
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Result TABLE
    (
        Id INT,
        IsDeleted BIT,
        DeleteDate DateTime
     )

     INSERT INTO @Result
     SELECT * FROM ExTest WHERE IsDeleted = 0

     UPDATE extest SET IsDeleted = 1

     SELECT * FROM @Result
END
GO
```

==================================================================

**C# Code:**

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
 {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateAndSelect", con))
     {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (dr.Read())
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Rows available {0} - {1} ", dr.GetFieldType(0), dr.GetInt32(0));

              }
          }
      }

 }
```

Here, when I run the SP at first time, All the records (those were not delete) will be moved to temp table, then all the records will be moved to delete state.

It will working fine when I run it in SQL server and provide a expected result. that means, When I run this SP in SQL server(2014 version), It will return Table data those are not moved to delete state. If I run this SP again it returns empty data. Because, after the select statement, I have moved all the record into delete state.

When I run this same SP through SqlCommend in C#, it doesn't return any value.

If I'm removing that update query `(UPDATE extest SET IsDeleted = 1)` or modifying the update query `(UPDATE extest SET DeleteDate = GETUTCDATE())` from SP, C# code will return below output
[image]

Based on my analysis, this issue will occurs, when I update a same field as I used in select statement's where condition. Here, I have updated a IsDeleted field in update query, and the same field will be used in select statement.

I had changed the SP as like below, still I can't able to get output from SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateAndSelect
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Result TABLE
    (
        Id INT,
        IsDeleted BIT,
        DeleteDate DateTime
    )

    DECLARE @UpdatedRecordIdList TABLE
    (
        Id INT
    )

    UPDATE extest SET IsDeleted = 1 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @UpdatedRecordIdList
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0

    INSERT INTO @Result
    SELECT * FROM ExTest WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @UpdatedRecordIdList)

    SELECT * FROM @Result
END
```

Does anyone faced this issue?
Can anyone help me to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Are you aware you are executing the command twice? ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteReader

Comment: It not answer your question, but why you need call to ExecuteNonQuery() in your code? If you want to get content of @Result table, ExecuteReader will be quite enough.

Comment: @vitalygolub actually that is the answer

Comment: @Crowcoder: You are right. I have removed ExecuteNonQuery(). Now it's working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` line from my code. Now it will be working fine.

**Reason for this issue:**

I had called both `ExecuteNonQuery()` and `ExecuteReader()` methods. Hence, the stored procedure has been executed twice. So, table values get's update on first execution. When run the same stored procedure on second time, it returns empty data.

When we consider above example:
Table values get updated when call `ExecuteNonQuery()` method. Now the table data will be look like below (IsDeleted field values updated from 0 to 1).

```
Id  IsDeleted   DeleteDate
1   1          2017-07-10 09:12:03.960
2   1          2017-07-10 09:12:07.000
```

When run `ExecuteReader()` method, all the records in the table was deleted. Hence, it doesn't return any value.